# How to split 64-integer into 2 32-bit integers?

Tags: c++11

Good day! I have already looked for solution of my problem, but I couldn't find any… At least all proposed solutions don’t work for me… Or I do smth wrong…

I have 64-bits integer:

```
{uint64_t st0 = 1470134824450120;}
```

I would like to get only the last 8-digits of this number, i.e. 24450120

I did for that the following:

```
uint32_t timestamp1 = 0;
uint32_t timestamp2 = 0;

timestamp2 = (uint32_t) st0;
timestamp1 = st0 >> 32;

printf("input:    %" PRIu64 "\n", st0);
printf("unpacked: %" PRIu32 " %" PRIu32 "\n", timestamp2, timestamp1);
```

As the result I have got:

```
input:    1470134824450120
unpacked: 1878767688 342292
```

What is wrong here?

Please, help me… I am not a student at university, I haven’t any advisor to help me…

Comment: If you want to get the last 8 digits: st0 % 100000000. I don't understand exactly what you want to obtain.

Comment: personally i'd cast uint64_t to an array of two uint32_t and go on from there

Answer (score 3):

So you have this number: 1470134824450120.

Its represantion in binary is:

00000000000001010011100100010100 01101111111110111011100001001000

After you compututation you have in variable *timestamp2* 1101111111110111011100001001000 in bits which is 1878767688 in decimal and in *timestamp1* 00000000000001010011100100010100 which is 342292 in decimal.

So the values are correct.

If you want to get the last 8 digits: st0 % 100000000

Answer (score 0):

Your title of the post asks for something other than you ask in your question.
If you want to split/cut a specific amount of decimal digits, it can not be done with operations as if you want binary digits.

If you really want to get the last 8 decimal digits, I suggest you to put this 64-bit integer to a buffer as string (e.g. sprintf), then cut the last 8 digits from this buffer and make an integer out of it (e.g. atol).

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried compiling but you can try this :)

```
#pragma pack(push)  /* push current alignment to stack */
#pragma pack(1)     /* set alignment to 1 byte boundary */
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint32_t a;
        uint32_t b;
    } decoupled;
    uint64_t value;
} MyUnsignedDecoupledInt64;
#pragma pack(pop)   /* restore original alignment from stack */

MyUnsignedDecoupledInt64 getDecoupledUnsignedInt64(uint64_t value)
{
    MyUnsignedDecoupledInt64 ret;
    ret.value = value;
    return ret;
}

int main() {

    MyUnsignedDecoupledInt64 t = getDecoupledUnsignedInt64(1000000000LL);
    printf("%u %u\n", t.decoupled.a, t.decoupled.b);

    return 0;
}
```